# How can I keep cells square in heatmap?

Tags: python, seaborn

When the cbar is on, the cells in seaborn's heatmap are rectangular.  I could change the figsize of my axis, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to keep the cells square.

Comment: Have a look at `plt.axis('equal')`

Comment: Have you tried the `square` argument? http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: @mwaskom oh that is embarrassing

Comment: Don't fret — there are very many!

Comment: I tried `square=True` and `ax.set_aspect("equal")` but neither doesn't fix bottom and top rows' units. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer Are they cut off?

Comment: My top and bottom row's cells are rectangular, with their widths matching the the other columns, but their heights are cut in half.

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer This is a bug in seaborn https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1773.  I think this can be rectified by changing the `ylim` of the axes.  The solution should be found in this github issue.

Answer (score 13):

seaborn heatmap has the option **square**:

```
heatmap(data, square=True)
```

Comment: I tried `square=True` and `ax.set_aspect("equal")` but neither doesn't fix bottom and top rows' units. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ax.set_aspect("equal")` to set an equal aspect ratio for the axes `ax`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(4,16)
ax = sns.heatmap(data)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried `square=True` and `ax.set_aspect("equal")` but neither doesn't fix bottom and top rows' units. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly needs to be fixed?

Comment: My top and bottom row's cells are rectangular, with their widths matching the the other columns, but their heights are cut in half.

Comment: Right. That is a [totally different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot/56942725#56942725).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I wouldn't say it's a "totally" different problem - like OP, I'm also trying to ensure the cells remain square.

Comment: It is, because your problem is independent of the colorbar.