# issue with differently sized cells in confusion matrix

Tags: matplotlib

Using the latest matplotlib version on Python 3.7 I try to plot (and save to png) a confusion matrix. While the resulting figure in in principle fine, the cells are sized different, see here:
[image: confusion matrix]

As you can see in the screenshot, actually only the middle cell is sized correctly, all others, i.e., all border cells in this case, seem to have only have half or even quarter the size compared to the middle cell.

The source code I'm running is simply:

```
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


def create_save_plotted_confusion_matrix(conf_matrix, expected_labels, basepath):
    ax, title = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_matrix, expected_labels, normalize=False)
    filepath = os.path.join(basepath, '.png')
    plt.savefig(filepath, bbox_inches='tight')


def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes, normalize=False, title=None, cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    if not title:
        if normalize:
            title = 'Normalized confusion matrix'
        else:
            title = 'Confusion matrix, without normalization'

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    else:
        pass

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(cm.shape[1]),
           yticks=np.arange(cm.shape[0]),
           # ... and label them with the respective list entries
           xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes,
           title=title,
           ylabel='True label',
           xlabel='Predicted label')

    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")

    # Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                    ha="center", va="center",
                    color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
    fig.tight_layout()

    return ax, title


if __name__ == '__main__':
    y_true = ["cat", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "bird"]
    y_pred = ["ant", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "cat"]
    confmat = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=["ant", "bird", "cat"])

    create_save_plotted_confusion_matrix(confmat, ["ant", "bird", "cat"], '.')
```

Comment: Duplicate of [matplotlib/seaborn: first and last row cut in half of heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot)

Comment: Is it really a duplicate, though? The issues in the question you're referring to is only about rows being cut off, whereas in my case also the columns are being cut off.

Comment: In the image you show, only the rows are affected. So yes, it's the same issue.