# Data of image plot in matplotlib and seaborn out of frame

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

The confusion matrix is displaying data out of frame. I tried resizing the figure where the figure area is changing but the data is still out of frame. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
cm = confusion_matrix(decoded_y_test, predictions)
cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm,
index = ['HIT','AVERAGE','FLOP'], 
columns = ['HIT','AVERAGE','FLOP'])

plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,4))
sns.heatmap(cm_df, annot=True)
```

Comment: This is a bug of matplotlib 3.1.1 [matplotlib/seaborn: first and last row cut in half of heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot)

Comment: See this answer for latest version that should work now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot/58924246#58924246

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to this [matplotlib/seaborn: first and last row cut in half of heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot)

What version of matplotlib are you using? Reverting to version 3.1.0 seemed to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm using 3.1.2 as I used the command from Anaconda website. Then to revert, should I uninstall 3.1.2 and then reinstall 3.1.0?