# sklearn confusion_matrix displaying with wrong dimensions / tick marks at wrong spots

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to display a confusion matrix and can't for the life of my figure out why it refuses to display in an appropriate manner. Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.winter):
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title, fontsize=30)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, fontsize=20)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes, fontsize=20)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.

    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt), horizontalalignment="center", 
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] < thresh else "black", fontsize=40)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label', fontsize=30)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label', fontsize=30)

    return plt

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predicted_counts)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plot = plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes=['Unsure','No','Yes'], normalize=False, title='Confusion matrix')
plt.show()
print(cm)
```

And this is what is displayed:

[image: bad confusion matrix]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib/seaborn: first and last row cut in half of heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the call to [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) you need to specify `origin='lower'` (the default is `'upper'`; they probably changed this at some time and the scikit-learn docs didn't update their [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py)). So the following should do the trick:

```
plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap, origin='lower')
#                                                    ^
#                                                    |
# added origin='lower'  ------------------------------
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

### Using Matplotlib

If you want to keep your matplotlib implementation, just add `plt.ylim(-0.5,2.5)` at the end of your plot_confusion_matrix function:

```py
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.winter):
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title, fontsize=30)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, fontsize=20)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes, fontsize=20)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.

    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt), horizontalalignment="center", 
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] < thresh else "black", fontsize=40)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label', fontsize=30)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label', fontsize=30)
    plt.ylim(-0.5, 2.5)  # <-- SOLUTION 

    return plt
```

### Using Seaborn

you can try the seaborn package for plotting heatmaps:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.winter):
  cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm, columns=classes, index = classes)
  cm_df.index.name = 'Actual'
  cm_df.columns.name = 'Predicted'
  plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
  sn.set(font_scale=1.4)#for label size
  ax =sn.heatmap(cm_df, cmap=cmap, annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 16},fmt="d")# font size
  plt.title(title)
  bottom, top = ax.get_ylim()
  ax.set_ylim(bottom + 0.5, top - 0.5)
  plt.show()

plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes=['Unsure','No','Yes'], normalize=False, title='Confusion matrix')
```

[Confusion Matrix Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66ItQ.png)

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're using matplotlib 3.1.1 which broke the tick default behaviour. Upgrade to 3.1.2 or downgrade to 3.1.0 to fix the issue.