# I can't see the full heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

**How to View my full heatmap?**

fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

corrmat=data.corr()

sns.heatmap(corrmat,annot=True)

plt.show()

[Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0pXT.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib/seaborn: first and last row cut in half of heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot)

Comment: yes but i dont find solution from that

Comment: From that same question thread, I like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58165593/10852841) if updating matplotlib isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update anaconda and update the matplotlib version

```
conda update matplotlib
```

Comment: i updated but it taking too much time.the cell is still in * mode