# Facing issue with seaborn.heatmap()

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, jupyter-lab

I'm using JupyterLab. When I was working on data visualization I encountered an issue with `seaborn.heatmap()`. The cells are uneven and the values inside the plot are not visible.
Here is the code snippet and the output.
[image: Seaborn]

I'm using *tips* dataset provided by `seaborn` library.
I even tried in IDLE, but faced same issue.

Is there a way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a problem related to **matplotlib** version that you are using. Take a look at this answer: [matplotlib/seaborn: first and last row cut in half of heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot)

But you can try to set the axis manually:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g=sns.heatmap(tips.corr(), annot= True)
g.set(ylim=(0,3))
g.set(xlim=(0,3))
```

[image: Plotting correctly]

I was able to reproduce the "bug" setting the axis in the following way:

```
g.set(ylim=(0.5,2.5))
g.set(xlim=(0,3))
```

[image: Reproduce bug]