# the yticks label is not aligned (the position not placed in the middle) in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to make heatmap with seaborn, but the ylabel and the parameter is not placed in the middle, I've been trying to add vertical alignment properties (line 3), but it's not work, here is the code:

```
data = np.random.rand(4, 4)
heat_map = sns.heatmap(data, annot=True)
plt.yticks(va="center")
plt.show()
```

And the result is look like this:
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDeiK.png)

When I make 2x2 heatmap, the result is look like this:
[The result 2x2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWCEo.png)

Looking forward to any tips or tricks that you have to offer to solve this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you remove `plt.yticks(va="center")`?

Comment: What matplotlib version are you using? You can look into [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/57245/seaborn-heatmap-not-displaying-correctly) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot) for possible solutions.

Comment: I'm trying to downgrade the matplotlib version and it's work!!! Thank you very much

Comment: I've tried to downgrade the matplotlib version to 3.1.0, and it's work. Thanks @DerekO

Comment: You could also upgrade to the latest version. It was an intermediate version (`matplotlib 3.1.1`) that didn't work well.