# plt.savefig does not save the images

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the next code:

```
heatmap = sns.clustermap(corrMatrix, row_colors=row_colors, 
                         #metric='correlation',
                         #method='single',
                         xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, 
                         cmap='coolwarm', annot=False, fmt=".2f", 
                         #annot_kws={'size':6}, square=False,
                         dendrogram_ratio=(.1, .2),
                         cbar_pos=(1, .2, .03, .4))

loc, labels = plt.xticks()
heatmap.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
heatmap.set_yticklabels(labels, rotation=0)
bottom, top = heatmap.get_ylim()
heatmap.set_ylim(bottom + 0.5, top -0.5)

heatmap.savefig(r'similarity' + '.svg', format='svg', dpi=600, bbox_inches = "tight" )
```

Works good but doesnt save the figure, only with this type of plot (clustermap) i was trying with `plt.savefig()` and `figure = heatmap.get_figure()` and nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crashing on the line `heatmap.set_xticklabels(...)` with

> `AttributeError: 'ClusterGrid' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'`

`sns.clustermap` is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions). It returns a `ClusterGrid` (axes-level functions return a matplotlib `ax`).

In seaborn's documentation, it is custom to call the return value of a figure-level function `g =` (with `g` being the first letter of 'grid'). If you start giving these variables very different names, it is easy to get lost in seaborn's documentation, and also when trying to use matplotlib functions for further customization.

The following code shows the intended naming conventions and the intended way to rotate the labels.  (I don't understand the changing the `ylim`s, maybe this is related to [an old problem with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot)? Changing the `ylim`s this way makes the plot look wrong.)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

g = sns.clustermap(np.random.rand(10, 10), row_colors=plt.cm.tab10.colors,
                   xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True,
                   cmap='coolwarm', annot=False, fmt=".2f",
                   dendrogram_ratio=(.1, .2),
                   cbar_pos=(1, .2, .03, .4))

g.ax_heatmap.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
g.ax_heatmap.tick_params(axis='y', rotation=0)
# labels = g.ax_heatmap.get_xticklabels()
# g.ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
# g.ax_heatmap.set_yticklabels(labels, rotation=0)
# bottom, top = g.ax_heatmap.get_ylim()
# g.ax_heatmap.set_ylim(bottom + 0.5, top - 0.5)

g.fig.savefig(r'similarity' + '.svg', format='svg', dpi=600, bbox_inches="tight")
```